WinRT prompt for MddBootstrapInitialize2 function suggests that this application cannot be started
I want the window to have a frosted glass effect, so I use windowsAppSdk in my win32 program. but when running into this code:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MddBootstrap.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>
#include <DispatcherQueue.h>
#include <WindowsAppSDK-VersionInfo.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR pszCmdLine,
    _In_ int iCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::single_threaded);

    const PACKAGE_VERSION minVersion{};
    hr = MddBootstrapInitialize2(
        Microsoft::WindowsAppSDK::Release::MajorMinor,
        Microsoft::WindowsAppSDK::Release::VersionTag,
        minVersion,
        MddBootstrapInitializeOptions_OnNoMatch_ShowUI
    );

    return 0;
}

It popped up with an error:
(caller: 00007FF88D149DC0) LogHr(1) tid(4784) 80040010 The object is not in  any state of in situ activityMsg:[Bootstrap.Intitialize: Scanning packages for Major.Minor=1.0, Tag=, MinVersion=0.0.0.0] CallContext:[\Initialize]

and
WinRT originate error - 0x80670016 : 'Unable to resolve package dependency conditions. \u000d\u000a'。

I also installed the package
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT" version="2.0.240405.15" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" version="10.0.26100.1" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" version="1.5.240627000" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>

I tried changing the majorMinorVersion to 0x0001000.But it's still the same error.

Check your Prerequisites and try that tutorial.

Please read [mre].

Is the Windows App SDK runtime installed on the machine? See Latest Windows App SDK downloads for the latest releases, or the archive for previous versions.
